# how to make simple datepicker dialog with buttons + and -?

Tags: android, dialog

I tried to make a `DatePicker` dialog based on some examples I read. I didn't achieve the desired result. I would appreciate any help and tutorials on this subjects for beginners.

Thanks in advance!

Any tutorial with example, please.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html. check the docs

Comment: I trried, but shows me en error on `show(getSupportFragmentManager()`

Comment: @Ana post the error with code

Comment: I just made class `DatePickerFragment` and copy from `developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html` and shows me `The method getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined for the type DatePickerFragment`

Comment: can you post the full code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the below for reference

pickerdate class

```
  public class pickerdate extends Activity {
    static TextView mDateDisplay;
    private Button mPickDate;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mDateDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        mPickDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        mPickDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
               // showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
                DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
                newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
            }
        });
    }   
    public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
    implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

        public EditText editText;
        DatePicker dpResult;

    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {

        mDateDisplay .setText(String.valueOf(day) + "/"
                + String.valueOf(month + 1) + "/" + String.valueOf(year));
    }
    }
}
```

main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Button" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="94dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```